# Requesting filesize and MIME type for a list of URLs in Android

Tags: android, http, urlconnection

In an Android application, I have a list of image URLs like this:

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(100);
urls.add("http://www.example.org/1.jpg");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/2.png");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/3.jpg");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/4.jpg");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/5.png");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/6.png");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/7.png");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/8.jpg");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/9.jpg");
urls.add("http://www.example.org/10.gif");
    ...
urls.add("http://www.example.org/100.jpg");
```

Now I have to get the filesize and MIME type for all of these URLs, and this should be done as fast as possible, of course.

What I did is the following:

```
for (String url : urls) {
    int fileSize;
    try {
        URLConnection urlConnection;
        urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        final String mimeType = urlConnection.getContentType();
        final int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        // do something with those two pieces of information
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        continue;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // some special handling
    }
}
```

But this is terribly slow. This is because it is using a single thread and requesting the URLs one by one, while a web browser would always access multiple files at a time, isn't it?

So how can I make it faster?

For `HttpClient`, I've read that you should re-use instances and there are some ways to use them in a multi-threaded environment.

But how would I do this with `URLConnection` or any other class that gives you filesize and MIME type?

**Edit:**

The images are not all on the same host, but spread across only a few servers, say 100 images spread across 5 host names.

Can you use a few threads or run several AsynTasks at once that do the job? Is there anything you have to pay attention to, such as recycling `URLConnection` objects or so?

I'm not quite sure how to [use multiple threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html) to share task list (100 image files) and merge the results (MIME types and file sizes) afterwards. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your work up into smaller peaces and let a worker `Thread` handle it:

The worker `Thread`:

```
public class Downloader extends Thread {

    private final String mUrl;
    private String mMimeType;
    private int mFileSize;

    public Downloader(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URLConnection urlConnection;
            urlConnection = new URL(mUrl).openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            mMimeType = urlConnection.getContentType();
            mFileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getMimeType() {
        return mMimeType;
    }

    public int getFileSize() {
        return mFileSize;
    }
}
```

Instantiate, run and wait for the worker:

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(10);
// ...
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(10);
for (String url : urls) {
    Thread t = new Downloader(url);
    threads.add(t);
    t.start();
}
for (Thread t : threads) {
    try {
        // do not wait for other threads  in main UI thread!
        t.join();
        //((Downloader) t).getMimeType();
        //((Downloader) t).getFileSize();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Make sure to note wait for the worker `Thread` in your UI `Thread`.

The answer above should only be used for a small set of URLs. A `ThreadPool` may not be necessary because the `Thread`s will wait for IO most of the time.

---

Here is your requested answer with a `ThreadPool`.

It's using the same `Downloader` class as the above example with only one change:
Spawning `Thread`s is done by the `ThreadPool` and the single tasks don't need to be a real `Thread` anymore. So let the `Downloader` implement a `Runnable` instead of extending a `Thread`:

```
public class Downloader implements Runnable {
```

Hopefully it's what you are looking for.

```
public class ThreadedDownloader {

    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 1;
    private static final TimeUnit KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    private static int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> mDecodeWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
    private ThreadPoolExecutor mDecodeThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_CORES,
            NUMBER_OF_CORES, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT, mDecodeWorkQueue) {
        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
            Downloader d = (Downloader) r;
            // do something with finished Downloader d
            // like saving it's result to some sort of list
            // d.getMimeType();
            // d.getFileSize();

            if (mDecodeWorkQueue.isEmpty()) {
                onAllDownloadsFinised();
            }
        }
    };

    /** Download a list of urls and check it's mime time and file size. */
    public void download(List<String> urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            mDecodeThreadPool.execute(new Downloader(url));
        }
    }

    /** Calles when all downloads have finished. */
    private void onAllDownloadsFinised() {
        // do whatever you want here
        // update UI or something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `setRequestMethod()` doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. And, by the way, you have to cast `URLConnection` to `HttpURLConnection` first for this to work. But is the threading thing really that simple? Creating one thread per task? What if I have 100 tasks? Will they be queued automatically? The Android docs suggest that it's much more complex, that you need to create thread pools etc: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html

Comment: You definitely should not create 100 threads at once. A ThreadPoolManager is a more complete solution. It creates some overhead but will protect you from spawning to much concurring Threads. If you are having only 10 simple non-CPU intensive tasks which will wait for IO most of the time, spawning just the Threads is fine.

Comment: Okay, so I could create my own simple "ThreadPool" by creating a `new Thread[3]` array, for example, right? But if I have 50 tasks (URLs) and only 3 threads, how do I proceed? It's not clear to me yet how to structure the loop(s), where to use `join()` etc. Could you maybe change your example so that it uses fewer threads for more tasks?

Comment: I don't think implementing your own ThreadPoolExecutor will work better than using the existing one. ;) -- I think you have two choices: use by answer and fire off all Threads at once, or use the existing ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @MarcoW. did you try the new answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for adding the ThreadPoolExecutor example! The problem is, aren't you setting both `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` to the number of cores? That means you are effectively creating a fixed thread pool, with 1 parallel thread on many devices and 2 threads on another large percentage of devices. Is this really necessary? This will not speed up things at all on lots of devices, right? Can't we just use an arbitrary number like 3 parallel threads? Furthermore, the docs are saying that you should create threads with a `ThreadFactory` like `defaultThreadFactory()`.

Comment: Well, then just use 3. As I said before, most of the time, the Threads are waiting for IO. So using a larger number that you would use for CPU intensive Threads is fine in you case.

Comment: I'm referencing these docs, by the way: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html Why aren't you using a `ThreadFactory`? Is it dispensable? Apart from that, I could see from the docs that your `LinkedBlockingQueue` is the perfect choice as we really have independent tasks :) And another thing, would you recommend `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`? Last thing: Why not use `newFixedThreadPool`? Sorry for all the questions! ;)

Comment: 1) i changed the 2nd part of the answer to use `Runnable` instead of `Thread`, because the threading is done by the `Excecuter` anyway. So there is no need for a `ThreadFactory` anymore. `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)` is a good choice, but I thought you throw away the whole Donwloader thing anyway. ;) `newFixedThreadPool` is fine too, but using the explicit Constructor with all the parameters seemed more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have example Code, but **the HTTP verb HEAD is what you're looking for**. It retrieves the headers (including mime and content-length) without transferring the content body.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461973/770517) goes into more detail about what HEAD does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have most, if not all of the pieces to your solution in the answers already submitted.

Here's what I'd do:

1) make the head requests using Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

2) store the responses in a Map

3) create a payload Map

4) load the real images using AsyncTask instances

5) when each bitmap load completes, store the results in the payload map

Just my thoughts.