# What does 'requests.head()' do in python requests?

Tags: python, http-head

```
import requests
send = requests.head('https://httpbin.org')
print(send.text)
```

What does 'requests.head()' do ? i get empty responses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the HTTP 'HEAD' verb useful in web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461937/is-the-http-head-verb-useful-in-web-development)

Comment: The `HEAD` / `.head` request is not specific to Python's requests package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A head request is a request used when you do not actually need the page content - just the status-code of your connection with the site or http-headers.

Comment: Indeed. Check out the `send.headers` for the response header details